# Android intent catch download CSV event from DEGIRO app

Tags: android, csv, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I'd like to open my app for downloading CSV created by another app (in my case is Banking DEGIRO app).

When I click on "CSV" icon CHROME, and Degiro itself, apps are offered for open the content.
If I choose Chrome a blank page appears and a CSV file is downloaded. So I suppose that the content is a https resource.

Via Catlog I see :
`START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://trader.degiro.nl/... cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity (has extras)}`

**Which intent filter I have to use ?**

*DEGIRO download CSV dialog*

[image: select CSV download]

---

*Suggested APPS*

[image: chrome suggested]

---

*Chrome downloading csv*

[image: download]